# Display unpersisted data in same list as persisted data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have two data sources: my database and a third party API. The third-party API is the "source of truth" but I want a user to be able to "bookmark" an `item` from the third-party API which will then persist it in my database.

The challenge I'm facing is displaying both sets of `item`s in the same list without too much complexity. Here's an example:

- Item 1 (not bookmarked, from third-party API)
- Item 2 (bookmarked, persisted locally)
- Item 3 (bookmarked, persisted locally)
- Item 4 (not bookmarked, from third-party API)

...etc

I want the view to fetch the list of all `item`s from the controller and have 0 idea of where the `item`s came from, but should only know whether or not each `item` is bookmarked so that it can be displayed (e.g. so the user can mark an unbookmarked `item` as bookmarked).

Generics would be one way to solve this in other languages, but alas, Ruby doesn't have generics (not complaining). In Ruby/Rails, what's the best way to wrap/structure these models so the view only has to worry about one type of `item` (when in reality there are two types behind the scenes?)

Comment: Are you asking how you should define your models and associations? OR do you already have some models and just want to fetch and merge the data with 3rd-party data?

Comment: If you have an array for each source's data, you can just combine the arrays. Maybe you should show the particular data structures you're working with to get more detailed advice.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest coming up with an object that takes care of fetching the items from both the third-party API and your database, the result of such operation would be an array of items that respond to the same methods, no matter where they came from.

Here's an example on how I'd go about it:

```
class ItemsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @items = ItemRepository.all
  end
end
```

In the code above `ItemRepository` is responsible for fetching items from both the database and the third party API, the view would then iterate over the `@items` instance variable.

Here's a sample implementation of the `ItemRepository`:

```
class ItemRepository
  def self.all
    new.all
  end

  # This method merges items from the API and
  # the database into a single array
  def all
    results_from_api + local_results
  end

  private

  def results_from_api
    api_items.map do |api_item|
      ResultItem.new(name: api_item['name'], bookmarked: false)
    end
  end

  # This method fetches the items from the API and
  # returns an array
  def api_items
    # [Insert logic to fetch items from API here] 
  end

  def local_results
    local_items.map do |local_item|
      ResultItem.new(name: local_item.name, bookmarked: true)
    end
  end

  # This method is in charge of fetching items from the 
  # database, it probably would use the Item model for this
  def local_items
    Item.all 
  end
end
```

The final piece of the puzzle is the `ResultItem`, remember  `ItemRepository.all` will be returning an array containing objects of this type, so all you need to do is store the information that the view needs from each item on this class.

In this example I assume that all the view needs to know about each item is its name and whether it has been bookmarked or not, so `ResultItem` responds to the `bookmarked?` and `name` methods:

```
class ResultItem
  attr_reader :name

  def initialize(name:, bookmarked:)
    @name = name
    @bookmarked = bookmarked
  end

  def bookmarked?
    !!@bookmarked
  end
end
```

I hope this helps :)

PS. Sorry if some of the class names are too generic I couldn't come up with anything better

Comment: Only concern here is that I would assume that this produces duplicates of the bookmarked items where by one is book marked (local) and the other is not (third party). I think some form of deduping would be required

Comment: That's a great point! If the API accepts some parameters when querying perhaps you could filter out the results stored locally, if not, I guess you could try to discard them manually as part of the `api_items` method